# How to build gnuradio without the documentation (from source)

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, gnuradio

I'm trying to build gnuradio 3.7.9 on raspberry pi as the version provided by apt-get has some problems.
However the classic `cmake/make/mke install` procedure tries to build the documentation which requires latex to be installed. As don't want to install latex, I'm looking for an option to build gnuradio without the documentation.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cmake will just disable documentation of it doesn't find doxygen. And if doxygen doesn't find LaTeX, it should just skip the formulas.

Anyway, use cmake with the -DENABLE_DOXYGEN=OFF flag.

More importantly, *don't build GNU Radio on the pi itself*. The raspberry pi is an embedded device, not a compilation platform, to be honest. RAM will quickly become a bottleneck, and together with the limited storage bandwidth that means that even if successful, the build will take days.

Instead, spend that time on fixing whatever is wrong with the packet. I do happen to know the maintainer of the Debian gnuradio packages, and he's a really nice guy. If you can write a good bug report, I'm sure he, or the [GNU Radio mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/discuss-gnuradio), will figure something out.